# Why is my very basic node.js endpoint timing out?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very simple node.js app that looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    return res.json({response: "ok"});
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
})
```

When I run `nodemon server`, I get this response from my terminal:

[image: A screenshot of my terminal showing that I'm connected to port 3000]

When I try to hit localhost:3000/, I get this:

[image: Screenshot of it trying to load a document?]

And in postman:

[image: Postman]

I feel like I must have set up something wrong, as I've stripped out all the code and I'm still getting this error. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking port 3000?

Comment: Not that I know of, and if I try it on port 5000, or any other port the same behaviour exists

Comment: A firewall could block everything not explicitly allowed, so changing the port number is not a strong test.

Comment: It's on personal machine that to my knowledge has no specific firewalls enabled

Comment: I feel like there's some clue about the fact that the network request tab has it trying to call a document rather than an api request? If I'm working in Laravel for example and I hit one of my endpoints, that ends up in the XHR section of the network request. These aren't. is that a clue?

Comment: Sometimes it can be because of browser extensions. Adblocks etc.

Comment: Same issue exists in Incognito mode

Comment: It works if I comment out app.use(cors)  not ideal but will do for now

Comment: Browsers only request documents, even if they are provided by what other entities refer to as end points. And most OSes have built-un firewall functionality nowadays (like Windows Firewall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

`app.use(cors())`

You have to invoke the function.